# Google BigQuery integration with PHP

Tags: php, api, integration, google-bigquery

I need a help to integrate google bigquery code into the PHP.
So i can execute query and other kind of operation from php code itself.

Need your help and suggest me some working examples link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a code that

- properly creates a `Google_Client` using https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client
- runs a job async
- displays the running job ID and status

You need to have:

- service account created (something like `...@developer.gserviceaccount.com`)
- your key file (`.p12`)
- service_token_file_location (writable path to store the JSON from the handshake, it will be valid for 1h)

code sample:

```
function getGoogleClient($data = null) {
    global $service_token_file_location, $key_file_location, $service_account_name;
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");

    $old_service_token = null;
    $service_token = @file_get_contents($service_token_file_location);
    $client->setAccessToken($service_token);
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
            $service_account_name, array(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control'
            ), $key
    );
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
        $service_token = $client->getAccessToken();
    }
    return $client;
}

$client = getGoogleClient();
$bq = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);

/**
 * @see https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#resource
 */
$job = new Google_Service_Bigquery_Job();
$config = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfiguration();
$config->setDryRun(false);
$queryConfig = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfigurationQuery();
$config->setQuery($queryConfig);

$job->setConfiguration($config);

$destinationTable = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableReference();
$destinationTable->setDatasetId(DATASET_ID);
$destinationTable->setProjectId(PROJECT_ID);
$destinationTable->setTableId('table1');

$queryConfig->setDestinationTable($destinationTable);

$sql = "select * from publicdata:samples.github_timeline limit 10";
$queryConfig->setQuery($sql);

try {
//    print_r($job);
//    exit;
    $job = $bq->jobs->insert(PROJECT_ID, $job);

    $status = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobStatus();
    $status = $job->getStatus();
//    print_r($status);
    if ($status->count() != 0) {
        $err_res = $status->getErrorResult();
        die($err_res->getMessage());
    }
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
//print_r($job);
$jr = $job->getJobReference();
//var_dump($jr);
$jobId = $jr['jobId'];
if ($status)
    $state = $status['state'];

echo 'JOBID:' . $jobId . " ";
echo 'STATUS:' . $state;
```

You can grab the results with:

```
$res = $bq->jobs->getQueryResults(PROJECT_ID, $_GET['jobId'], array('timeoutMs' => 1000));

if (!$res->jobComplete) {
    echo "Job not yet complete";
    exit;
}
echo "<p>Total rows: " . $res->totalRows . "</p>\r\n";
//see the results made it as an object ok
//print_r($res);
$rows = $res->getRows();
$r = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableRow();
$a = array();
foreach ($rows as $r) {
    $r = $r->getF();
    $temp = array();
    foreach ($r as $v) {
        $temp[] = $v->v;
    }
    $a[] = $temp;
}
print_r($a);
```

You can see here the classes that you can use for your other BigQuery calls. When you read the file, please know that file is being generated from other sources, hence it looks strange for PHP, and you need to learn reading it in order to be able to use the methods from it.

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Bigquery.php

like:

- Google_Service_Bigquery_TableRow

Also check out the questions tagged with [php] and [google-bigquery] 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-bigquery+php

Comment: i am stucked with code. Can u plz  help me out.
---
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Could not json decode the token' in C:\xampp\htdocs\big02\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php:179 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\big02\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Client.php(215): Google_Auth_OAuth2->setAccessToken(false) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\big02\home.php(12): Google_Client->setAccessToken(false) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\big02\home.php(28): getGoogleClient() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\big02\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 179

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Could not json decode the token' in C:\xampp\htdocs\big02\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php:179 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\big02\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Client.php(215): Google_Auth_OAuth2->setAccessToken(false) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\big02\home.php(11): Google_Client->setAccessToken(false) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\big02\home.php(29): getGoogleClient() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\big02\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 179

Comment: you need to make a writable file to store the token, also you need to setup correct p12 service file (from your service account) + you need to have JSON support in your PHP installation.

Comment: do u have working setup folder structure of this program. so you can send me on my mail id or we have chat over there. If you are ok to share with me the let me know.  This will be very useful for me. I have both the p12 and JSON file in folder. but could not able to exe it.

Comment: amitpatange88@gmail.com

Comment: thanks in advance. I have also read your comment in 16 jan. anyway thanks. and plz send me the working copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following steps

1. In the Cloud Console, on the project selector page, select or create a Cloud project
2. Enable the BigQuery API.
3. Set up authentication
4. In the Cloud Console, go to the Create service account key page.
5. Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the path of the JSON file that contains your service account key. This variable only applies to your current shell session, so if you open a new session, set the variable again

For full guide please see this doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#bigquery_simple_app_client-php)