# Generating token for JWT Auth BigQuery API

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, jwt, google-oauth

I read the documentation of [Google OAuth2.0 for server to server application](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and tried searching online but could not find reference for creating and renewing OAuth2.0 Token for **Bigquery API** I tried generating it by my self using the documentation but still in vain

Please help me

Below is the code I used to get the Json Web Token

```
<?php
    $header = '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}';

    $header = base64_encode($header);

    $claims = '{"iss":"account-1@euphoric-quanta-114611.iam.gserviceaccount.com","scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token","exp":"'.(time()+3000).'","iat":"'.time().'"}';

    $claims = base64_encode($claims);

    $encodedContent = $header . "." . $claims;

    $signature = hash_hmac("SHA256",$encodedContent, '{my private key}');


    $signature = base64_encode($signature);

    $data = $header.".".$claims.".".$signature;

    echo $data;
?>
```

later I sending post request to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` with `assertion` as value generated by code and `grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer` and I got following response

```
    {
      "error": "invalid_grant",
      "error_description": "Bad Request"
    }
```

What mistake I am making and where can I find complete documentation for JWT auth token for Big Query API

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `.` is the PHP string concatenation operator, not `+`

Comment: Sorry It's a typo, I am trying using . operator

Comment: @self I have updated my question

Comment: Why don't you use a PHP library that already does this for you https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: For that also I will need Access token for authorized API access according to their documentation https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started @Pentium10

Comment: You need those details from the console, and you don't need to build a script for it. See example code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30477858/google-bigquery-integration-with-php/30478266#30478266

Comment: I will try, thank you for your help @Pentium10